# How to position icons on same line in bootstrap navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Icons are one below the other, how to fix this ?:

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FD6MX1ONETFC

[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Bootstrap Case</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar"> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a> </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown"> <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></a> <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="container">
  <h3>Collapsible Navbar</h3>
  <p>In this example, the navigation bar is hidden on small screens and replaced by a button in the top right corner (try to re-size this window).
  <p>Only when the button is clicked, the navigation bar will be displayed.</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're just missing a beginning `<li>` for your log-in glyphicon.

Comment: @maxshuty I just updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the anchor tag in separate  `LI` to bring the next icon on same line, following is the updated code:

**UPDATE:**
You can override the existing bootstrap CSS and update the padding of anchor tag from left and right without affecting left navigation, just add the following CSS:

```
.navbar-right > li > a {
  padding-left: 5px !important;
  padding-right: 5px !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Bootstrap Case</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar"> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a> </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown"> <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="container">
  <h3>Collapsible Navbar</h3>
  <p>In this example, the navigation bar is hidden on small screens and replaced by a button in the top right corner (try to re-size this window).
  <p>Only when the button is clicked, the navigation bar will be displayed.</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry I just updated my question: that was my first attempt but there was too much space between the icons.

Comment: @user310291 I have just updated my answer as per your requirement.

Comment: OK that's the right answer for my question. But I asked another one because the icons have too much space in between http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42494703/bootstrap-icons-are-blue-instead-of-white-and-not-well-positionned-vertically

Comment: you can control the space between those icons by updating padding-left and padding-right as the CSS I have posted in my answer, I would recommend to keep separate LI for both the icons BTW

Answer (score 1):

Because you have put both icons in same li tag

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></a>
      <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span></a></li>
    </ul>
```

instead of that put them in saperate li tag

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li>
        <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></a>
   </li>
   <li>
      <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span></a>
  </li>
    </ul>
```