# Bootstrap icons are blue instead of white and not well positioned vertically

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want two icons next to each other (nearly no space between them), I put them in same li and same div but they are now blue and not well positionned vertically, what bootstrap class or custom style or anything else should I use (just putting in 2 li doesn't make it, the icons have too much space between them) ? :

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FD6NR1HEOO3W

[image]

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li>
          <div class="btn-group">
            <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></a>
            <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span></a>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="container">
  <h3>Collapsible Navbar</h3>
  <p>In this example, the navigation bar is hidden on small screens and replaced by a button in the top right corner (try to re-size this window).
    <p>Only when the button is clicked, the navigation bar will be displayed.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not use `<div>` inside `<li>`
I have used two different `li` for both icons and added two classes, check below snippet:

**Note:** You can adjust space between icons using by increasing padding

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css');

.navbar-right li{
  display:inline-block
}
.navbar-right li .left_padd {
  padding-left:0;
}
.navbar-right li .right_padd {
  padding-right:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li>
          
            <a class="right_padd" href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></a><li>
            <li><a class="left_padd" href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span></a></li>
         
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="container">
  <h3>Collapsible Navbar</h3>
  <p>In this example, the navigation bar is hidden on small screens and replaced by a button in the top right corner (try to re-size this window).
    <p>Only when the button is clicked, the navigation bar will be displayed.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is you have `<div class="btn-group">` and you don't need it, also you have the two buttons inside only one `<li>`.

This is your code:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li>
      <div class="btn-group">
        <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></a>
        <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span></a>
      </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and should be like this: only one `<li>` per button, without the `btn-group` div:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span></a></li>
</ul>
```

Here is an example: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FD6OLHFYBBWZ

Comment: Don't write in text-speak.  Spell out "you", not "u".

Comment: im new at english language, so im learning :) anyways i dont see a rule for that. i invite you to read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice at the point two :) also there is a button to propose an edition of the answer, you should use that instead comments sections...

Comment: I think cale_b's comment is more about appearing professional and having your solution be taken seriously than _"not being welcoming"_ to new users. Not spelling out words appears juvenile and lazy. You wouldn't use text speak on a job application would you? Simply editing your text speak wouldn't help you become a more credible/competent contributor to SO. At least that's how I took/see it.

Answer (score 2):

Apply color:white and padding-top to the spans that contain .glyphicon. This should help.

Answer (score 2):

Change the markup for your nabvar containing the glyphicons from this:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
  <li>
    <div class="btn-group">
      <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></a>
      <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span></a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

to:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
  <li>
    <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="container">
  <h3>Collapsible Navbar</h3>
  <p>In this example, the navigation bar is hidden on small screens and replaced by a button in the top right corner (try to re-size this window).
    <p>Only when the button is clicked, the navigation bar will be displayed.</p>
</div>
```

Or, don't create a second navbar at all.

Change:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
  <li>
    <div class="btn-group">
      <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></a>
      <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span></a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

to:

```
<p class="navbar-text navbar-right">
  <a class="navbar-link" href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></a>
  <a class="navbar-link" href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span></a>
</p>
```

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
      </ul>
      <p class="navbar-text navbar-right">
        <a class="navbar-link" href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></a>
        <a class="navbar-link" href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span></a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="container">
  <h3>Collapsible Navbar</h3>
  <p>In this example, the navigation bar is hidden on small screens and replaced by a button in the top right corner (try to re-size this window).
    <p>Only when the button is clicked, the navigation bar will be displayed.</p>
</div>
```